# Software that makes multiple avi files from mini-DV tape

Tags: windows, mini-dv

A few years ago, I had a copy of Roxio DVD Builder version 6 that I used to transfer videos from my Mini-DV camcorder to my computer.  That version of DVD Builder would create multiple avi files - one for every time I stopped/started the camera.

I stopped using that camcorder for a while but now have a new one and I find that the newer versions of Roxio I have and Windows Movie Maker all want to transfer my video as one big avi file (~15GB).  Internally, I can access individual clips, but the only way I can find to break the big avi file into small ones is to go one by one through the clips and save them.  With 60-odd clips per tape, that's too much work.

So I'm wondering if there is any Windows software that behaves the way my old Roxio v6 did - i.e. that transfers the videos as individual avis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forget where I found the link to it, I went with [WinDV](http://windv.mourek.cz/).  It's small and works, it will automatically name each avi with a serial number.  It seems to drop frames a bit more than I remember Roxio do, but these are jerky home movies anyway, so that doesn't bother me.

Answer (score 1):

Sony Vegas' capture software can do this. However, this might not be an option because of its price.

Much better alternatives are discussed in [this thread](http://www.dvinfo.net/conf/non-linear-editing-pc/146203-split-scene-timecode-scene-avi.html). Their advice is [AVCutty](http://www.avcutty.de/english/index.htm) and [DVdate](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/DVdate). Another software capable of splitting your video is [Exsate DV Capture Live](http://wareseeker.com/Video/exsate-dv-capture-live-1.1.0.311.zip/361121) .

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe Premiere Elements](http://www.adobe.com/products/premiereel/) will do the trick aswell.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [ScenalyzerLive](http://www.scenalyzer.com/main.html) for years to do this. Hasn't been updated in a while, but works well, naming captured clips as they come in based on date/time, etc. Costs $35.